# How to supress output from library code in cppcheck?

Tags: cppcheck

Running cppcheck on my project gives me about 80% ouput about library files instead of my code.

Is there a way to tell cppcheck to only search library(-headers) for definitions and such but not actually perform checks?

Or at least to supress the output for those files?

Or, even better, save the gathered information somewhere for re-use, as the library code is not likely to change for the next run?

Answer (score 1):

I am a Cppcheck dev. Not currently. But I do believe that we should not warn about library headers.

Feel free to write some comments here if you want:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/3390

Comment: I've rather commented in your new ticket https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/5567, because it actually askes for input. Thanks.

Comment: @Chaos_99 So is this fixed? both tickets don't seem to exist anymore...

Comment: It was moved: http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/3390  .. unfortunately it's not fixed yet.